# How to run a script in daemon mode without output getting in the way?

Tags: unix, process, logging, daemon

I know how to run a script in daemon mode (add a & to it):

mycmd -y config.yaml run&

However, the script I'm running has lots of "print" statements, which ruin my output.  Is there a way to say "output this to log.txt"?

This didn't work:

```
mycmd -y config.yaml run& >> log.txt
```

Hmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it:

`mycmd -y config.yaml run >> log.txt 2>&1 &`

The `2>&1` merges `stderr` into `stdout` so that everything goes into `log.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `nohup *command* > log.txt &`